# Range function argument returning typeerror: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python-3.x, range, typeerror

I'm new to programming and I've just started learning python. Sorry for the long post and any help will be appreciated.

Write a program that prints the integers from 1 to 100. But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number, and for the multiples of five print "Buzz". For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz".

Code:

```
my_list = [x for x in range(1,101)]
```

```
for number in my_list:
    if number%3 ==0 and number%5 ==0:
        my_list[number] = "FizzBuzz"
    elif number%3 == 0:       
        my_list[number] = "Fizz"
    elif number%5 == 0:
        my_list[number] ="Buzz"
```

**My program is return this error shown below: **

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_5324\196912280.py in <module>
      7 
      8 for number in my_list:
----> 9     if number%3 ==0 and number%5 ==0:
     10         my_list[number] = "FizzBuzz"
     11     elif number%3 == 0:

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

but when I change the value of start in range function to 0

my_list = [x for x in range(0,101)]

```
for number in my_list:
    if number%3 ==0 and number%5 ==0:
        my_list[number] = "FizzBuzz"
    elif number%3 == 0:       
        my_list[number] = "Fizz"
    elif number%5 == 0:
        my_list[number] ="Buzz"
    
print(my_list)
```

It worked well. I can't figure out the reason behind it. Maybe it has something to do with the interpreter.
Any help will be appreciated.

Output:

```
['FizzBuzz', 1, 2, 'Fizz', 4, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 7, 8, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 11, 'Fizz', 13, 14, 'FizzBuzz', 16, 17, 'Fizz', 19, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 22, 23, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 26, 'Fizz', 28, 29, 'FizzBuzz', 31, 32, 'Fizz', 34, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 37, 38, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 41, 'Fizz', 43, 44, 'FizzBuzz', 46, 47, 'Fizz', 49, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 52, 53, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 56, 'Fizz', 58, 59, 'FizzBuzz', 61, 62, 'Fizz', 64, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 67, 68, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 71, 'Fizz', 73, 74, 'FizzBuzz', 76, 77, 'Fizz', 79, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 82, 83, 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 86, 'Fizz', 88, 89, 'FizzBuzz', 91, 92, 'Fizz', 94, 'Buzz', 'Fizz', 97, 98, 'Fizz', 'Buzz']
```

Comment: Which version is the Python's interpreter?

Comment: @slouchart Python 3.9.13